# How to access page from outside React App

Tags: routes

I am new to ReactJs. I wants to access page from outside of react app. example-

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/Apply" component={Apply} />
    <Route exact path="/Team" component={Team} />
</Switch>
```

My app has 3 pages, homepage is Home, it has two link Apply and Team. Suppose url of homepage is "https://xyz" Whenver I search "https://xyz/Team" in google it shows page does not exist but if accessed from homepage the url shown is "https://xyz/Team". App is hosted on firebase. I would be thankful if anyone can help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it is seemingly feasible, there are some impediments that you can't avoid. The major thing is that React works in the client-side, therefore there is no way to render different routes by typing them into the browser.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/9599137) is a well-detailed answer, perhaps this will be satisfying and answer all the other questions that aroused in your mind.